# Uninstalling versus disabling apps

Tags: applications, delete, app-icons, disable-app, app-drawer

When I select the menu entry called "Uninstall/Disable apps" - from the apps drawer which can be reached from any home screen by tapping the 16-square icon in the lower-right hand corner - I can disable or delete any apps. However, clicking on an app disables it. I remember being able to uninstall apps by dragging them to a delete trash can icon. I cannot figure out how to delete an app on the apps drawer.

Also, while I realize this might vary from app to app, what would be some of the most common reasons/advantages to disabling an app?

P.S. I think the screens accessible by clicking the 16-square icon are what is called the app drawer, correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks.

I am on a Samsung Galaxy SIII (Android KitKat 4.4.2) and I am cussing the default TouchWiz launcher.

(I would have liked to attach screenshots but at the moment my network connection is slow).

Comment: Are you using a different launcher? TouchWiz, the standard launcher for Samsung devices, doesn't delete apps this way, nor does it disable them. This action WILL delete a widget and app from the homescreen. Additionally, and the reason I ask about a different launcher, is that Nova Launcher ADDs functions to allow Uninstall/Remove apps this way. Maybe you were using Nova, and went back to standard TouchWiz?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post, I am using TouchWiz. Please let me know how to delete an app with TouchWiz. I will also try Nova launcher, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to uninstall apps on touch-wiz, go to the apps folder then tap the left soft button. Now tap uninstall and touch the **minus button** for the app you want to remove. Finally, tap yes when it says "(App you chose) will be uninstalled". Here is a video showing how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYL6nYapr7I

> Also, while I realize this might vary from app to app, what would be
>   some of the most common reasons/advantages to disabling an app?

The advantage of disabling an app over uninstalling it is that the app doesn't need to be installed all over again (from scratch using WiFi and the google play store.) Instead, you can find the app you want to use again and enable it. Think of it as a file in the recycling bin of a PC. It is not being used by the computer by any way, but can still be restored and put to use if you wish so.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, but does this mean that to uninstall an app I first have to drag it from the apps folder to one of the home screens, and then delete it. Why can't I do this directly from the apps folder?

Comment: That is probably just the way touch-wiz was designed. There are plenty of other launchers however like nova in which you can alter this setting.

Comment: @Devin - what device and OS are you providing this action from? I, similar to Jack, have an S3, where this doesn't hold. Maybe you're speaking of a revision since?

Comment: I used a samsung note 2 running kitkat. I found that it is different than on mine now and have revised the answer. Here is a video showing how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYL6nYapr7I. Apparently you have to first hit the left soft button in then click uninstall.